# $_POST & Special Characters

Tags: php

I'm using AES Encryption and trying to send this string via a $_POST Send (with CURL).

This is the string: cpZa˜Hó”™itz²÷ðt?=þ|w±I†ïÛì„¡

When I send it it shows up looking quite different.
Is it possible to send characters like this via $_POST?
Is there a way to do this?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary data should be encoded (usually as Base64) before transmitting so that there can be no ambiguity when the other side reads it and no issues with newlines across different systems.